$( A \subseteq B \land B\subset C ) \implies (A \subset C) $ [ proof by quantification theory]
I had a problem to find out the proper quantified sentence to prove this theorem. I saw an answer in this platform and here's the link. But I want to prove the theorem using only logic (I mean quantification theory). My approach is as follows:
$( A \subseteq B \land B\subset C ) \iff (\forall x)(x\in A \implies x\in B) \land (\forall x)(\exists y) ((x\in B\implies x\in C) \land (y\in C \land y\notin B)) \iff  (\forall x)((x\in A \implies x\in B) \land (x\in B\implies x\in C))   \land (\exists y)  (y\in C \land y\notin B) \implies  (\forall x)(x\in A \implies x\in C)  \land (\exists y)  (y\in C \land y\notin B)$
Now, I just have to replace $(\exists y)  (y\in C \land y\notin B)$ by $(\exists y)  (y\in C \land y\notin A)$ from the existing information to complete the proof. This is where I got stuck. I, however, have the information that, $ A\subseteq B \iff (\forall y)(y\in A \implies y\in B)$ which is equivalent to, $ \neg (\exists y) \neg (y\in A \implies y\in B)$ which is also equivalent to, $ \neg (\exists y) (y\in A \land y\notin B)$. But this sentence isn't helpful to fulfill the replacement. So, how should I prove this sentence($(\exists y)  (y\in C \land y\notin A)$). Any possibilities?
Another approach to the proof can be like this where I am also stuck. I mean I am actually confused whether my attempt is perfect mathematically or not. So, basically this approach is little bit more successful than the previous one.
$( A \subseteq B \land B\subset C ) \iff  (A \subseteq B \land B\subseteq C \land B≠C) \iff (A \subseteq C \land B≠C) \iff ? $

$((x\in A) \implies (x \in B)) \iff ((x\notin B) \implies (x\notin A))$

This condition comes with the quantifiers $ \forall $ . Can we say it's also true for the quantifier $ \exists $.

If it's true for all $x$ then in particular it's true for your existentially quantified $y$...

@NaïmFavier what will be the relation between them? I mean are they equivalent? For example can we say this is correct? $ A\subseteq B \iff (\forall x)((x\in A) \implies (x \in B)) \iff (\forall x)((x\notin B) \implies (x\notin A)) \color{red}{\iff} (\exists x)((x\notin B) \implies (x\notin A))$

The first equivalence is by definition, the second is true classically (the $\implies$ direction is constructive), the third is not an equivalence (in fact neither direction is true in general).

You said neither direction is true. Then how will you represent your first comment in a formal proof. In the question I reached
$( A \subseteq B \land B\subset C ) \iff  (\forall x)((x\in A \implies x\in B) \land (x\in B\implies x\in C))   \land (\exists y)  (y\in C \land y\notin B) $.
Here are two separate sentences. First one can be easily replaced by transitivity of conditional formula. But in case of second one $(\exists y)  (y\in C \land y\notin B) $ I have to show $ y\notin B \implies y\notin A$. Please write the rest of the proof that proves $ y\notin B \implies y\notin A$.

What is the difference between $\subset$ and $\subseteq$?

Proper subset vs. subset.

Since you're struggling to see how to apply a universally quantified statement under an existential quantifier, let's prove that $(\forall x. P(x) \to Q(x)) \land (\exists y. P(y))$ implies $(\forall x. P(x) \to Q(x)) \land (\exists y. Q(y))$. In $\lambda$-calculus:
$$\lambda (f, y, p). (f, y, f(y, p))$$
Translating this into natural deduction gives something like:

assume $(\forall x. P(x) \to Q(x)) \land (\exists y. P(y))$
by 1 and left $\land$-elimination, $\forall x. P(x) \to Q(x)$
by 1 and right $\land$-elimination, $\exists y. P(y)$
by 3 and $\exists$-elimination, $P(y)$
by 2 and $\forall$-elimination, $P(y) \to Q(y)$
by 4, 5 and $\to$-elimination, $Q(y)$
by $\exists$-introduction, $\exists y. Q(y)$
by 2, 7 and $\land$-introduction, $(\forall x. P(x) \to Q(x)) \land (\exists y. Q(y))\ \square$

I will leave it up to you to adapt this to the statement you want to prove and the formal system you want to prove it in.
Elaborating on my comment, note that $\forall x. P(x) \to Q(x)$ does not imply $\exists x. P(x) \to Q(x)$: there might not be any $x$ at all (consider the empty set)! Instead, it implies $(\exists x. P(x)) \to (\exists x. Q(x))$, which is what we use here.


Another approach to the proof can be like this where I am also stuck. I mean I am actually confused whether my attempt is perfect mathematically or not. So, basically this approach is little bit more successful than the previous one.
$(A⊆B∧B⊂C)⟺(A⊆B∧B⊆C∧B≠C)⟺(A⊆C∧B≠C)⟺?$

Try $(A\subseteq B\wedge B\subset C) \iff ((A\subset B\vee A=B)\wedge B\subset C) ~~\ldots$
[This approach does not use quantification, although you may use it to construct a quantified proof.]

This is a good one but then I have to prove the transitivity of proper subset before proceeding. So, I didn't go that way.
